# How do I log the spark-submit command line that I typed?

Tags: apache-spark, logging, command-line, pyspark

How do I write a PySpark script that will log the spark-submit command line into its log output?

For example, when I run:
`spark-submit script.py arg1 arg2 --flag arg3 --out output`

in addition to running its task, I want this command to record that command line into a log file called output.log so I can easily keep track of how I ran it.

Comment: Is it possible to store the command line in `logger.info()`, where `logger = logging.getLogger(results.app_name)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a shell script to execute spark-submit, with given arguments

```
@echo off
echo spark-submit script.py %1 %2 --flag %3 --out output >> output.log 
spark-submit script.py %1 %2 --flag %3 --out output >> output.log
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but would it possible to do it from within script.py? I'm just thinking about decreasing the number of scripts I would need to have.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script or python script to execute the command. This will act as a wrapper within which you can log the output to a file. In python you can use `os.system()` to execute spark-submit